# How to get all different dropdown have selected value or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check that all dropdown on page have select value or not?

fox Ex:-

```
<select id="@model.Id">
     <option value="0">---</option>
     <option value="1">abc</option>
     <option value="2">xyz</option>
</select>

<select id="@model.Id">
     <option value="0">---</option>
     <option value="14">abc</option>
     <option value="25">xyz</option>
</select>
```

Both are not same page and and issue there is dynamic id and name are assign to both of dropdrop down so i can't use jQuery by id or name and get selected value, not i want to check that both have selected value by Javascript or jQuery?

How can I do this?

Regards,
Vinit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : you can iterate all `select` boxes on page using `.each()` and compare it's value with `0`. If select value is `0` it means it is not selected otherwise selected.

```
$(function(){
  $('select').each(function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     if(value==0)
       alert('this dropdown has no selected value, id = '+id);
     else
       alert('this dropdown has selected value, id = '+id);
  }):
});
```

**Edit** - as OP want to check if both dropdowns selected then show button otherwise hide it, use below code

```
$(function(){
      $('select').change(function(){
        var totalUnselectedDropdown = $('select option[value="0"]:selected').length;
        if(totalUnselectedDropdown==0)
        {
          // enable button
          $('#buttonId').prop('disabled',false);
        }
        else
        {
          // disable button
          $('#buttonId').prop('disabled',true);
        }

      }):
    });
```

Comment: Can i get both dropdown value at same time, this function check value in for loop like, if 1st dropdown is not selected means 0 and 2nd is selected then i got 2nd value but i want to check both, can you suggest me

Comment: do you want to get how many dropdowns are selected from available drowdown, is that what you want to know?

Comment: yes, see i want to hide one button, if any of dropdown is not selected,and on change event of that dropdown check wether both are selected then show that button

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
$("select").each(function(){

alert($(this).val()) // will alert selected option value attribute value

if($(this).val() > 0) // value greater than 0 means value selected
{
 alert("Value Selected")
}

})
```

Comment: Can i get both dropdown value at same time, this function check value in for loop like, if 1st dropdown is not selected means 0 and 2nd is selected then i got 2nd value but i want to check both, can you suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("select").each(function(){
            if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0){
                //all select have selected value
            }
            else
            {
                //any one/all select have not selected value
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can i get both dropdown value at same time, this function check value in for loop like, if 1st dropdown is not selected means 0 and 2nd is selected then i got 2nd value but i want to check both, can you suggest me

Comment: I think Removing `return false;` works for u.Please try and then let me know it works OR not

Comment: No,it's working same as, means if i write return false or not, no cahgne